Filing a Tax Return that is not quite right
A hypothetical person knows that he is  better off itemizing than taking  the standard  deduction. However, he does not have time to do the return properly and get it in by April  15. He does the return taking the standard deduction and the return shows that he has money due. He then files the return but he does not pay. Seven months later, he files an amended return which shows that he is getting money back.
Did  he break the law? Can/will the  IRS  do anything unpleasant to him?

Why doesn't Bob just request an extension to file his return? That takes far less time and effort than filling out a return.

@bdb484 Filing an extension makes sense to me. However, it does not give tax payer only 6 months to file the return. In my hypothetical situation, the taxpayer needs 7 months to do his return. What the tax payer should really do is hiring a competent tax preparer who can do the job correctly in a timely manner.


Did he break the law? Can/will the IRS do anything unpleasant to him?

The law allows the taxpayer to elect standard deduction instead of itemizing even if it is not in their favor economically. See the IRC Sec. 63(e).
The IRC Sec. 63(e)(3) explicitly allows changing the election to itemize after filing (special case of MFS returns is handled in IRC Sec. 63(e)(3)(A) and (B)).
So no, no laws broken.
It is however extremely inefficient, unnecessarily expensive, and may potentially trigger unnecessary attention.
A proper course of action would be to request automatic extension via form 4868 and file a proper return when all the information is available during the extension period.
It should not generally take so long to be able to file a return for the year for an individual. 7 months after April 15th would be close to the second year after the tax year in question. This seems unreasonably long, and may lead to the IRS looking into what is going on (i.e.: trigger an audit). If numbers are kosher, however, it shouldn't result in any adverse action just because of the delay as long as no tax is due.

Well, as the IRS says, " Make sure you pay any tax you owe by the April filing date" - here is the potential rub. They file a return that results in tax being owed but don't pay it in April. The IRS does not know that they intend to file an amended return later. At best it could be an uncomfortable letter or two back and forth.

Yes, as I said, this scenario may bring some unnecessary attention and waste of time (and potentially money) to respond to these uncomfortable letters. But if there's no tax owed in the end - there will be no penalty. Since the tax was never owed, even if the original return showed some.

Indeed, it might end up a wash. On the other hand, if you do enough work to know you won't owe taxes by itemizing then you should file that return, and file an amended return later showing more itemized deductions.

@JonCuster You're only penalized for failing to pay taxes you actually owe. If you mistakenly think you owe tax, but don't actually owe it, there's no penalty. The basic IRS instructions probably assume that your return is an accurate calculation of your tax.

You can't file and just "not pay."  The IRS will send you a bill if you don't include payment and your debt will start to accrue interest.
I imagine that when the amended return is filed, the IRS will deduct the interest owed from the refund.

You absolutely can file and just "not pay" at the time of filing. Indeed, the Internal Revenue Code is designed to encourage you to do just that. The penalty for failing to file a tax return is 5% of the tax owed per month (plus interest on the late payment). The penalty for filing a tax return but not paying is 0.5% of the tax owed per month (plus interest on the late payment). The IRS may send you a bill for the amount you said you owed but didn't pay, but it takes many months or years for them to actually get around to trying to collect it.

Interest and penalties are calculated based upon the amount actually owed, so if the amended return is accepted and valid, there won't be a monetary penalty for doing so.
